# can we call overridden function on the basis of their arguments without using virtual function?

Tags: c++

```
class mca1
{
    public:
        void power(float m,int n)
        {
           cout<<"RESULT OF "<<m<<"^"<<n<<"="<<pow(m,n);
        }
};
class mca2:public mca1
{
    public:
        void power(int m,int n)
        {
            cout<<"\nRESULT OF "<<m<<"^"<<n<<"="<<pow(m,n);
        }
};
```

please tell me is there any way to call overridden functions without use of virtual function....just on the basis of arguments?

Comment: Just `mca1::power`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull the base class function into the derived class scope, making them behave as overloaded functions.

```
class mca1
{
    public:
        void power(float m,int n)
        {
           cout<<"RESULT OF "<<m<<"^"<<n<<"="<<pow(m,n);
        }
};
class mca2:public mca1
{
    public:
        using mca1::power;
        void power(int m,int n)
        {
            cout<<"\nRESULT OF "<<m<<"^"<<n<<"="<<pow(m,n);
        }
};
```

Comment: it is giving error "call of overloaded power(double,int) is ambigous

Comment: If you try to call it with a double, it will do that since both conversions are valid. If you call it with a float or int it will do the right thing. `mca2 m; m.power(2.0, 1);` will fail but `m.power(2.9f, 1);` and `m.power(2, 1);` will work.

Comment: You can add one more overload for double if you need both to work. Maybe even just forward to the float version. That's just how function overloading in `c++` works.

Comment: is there any specific reason that double works without any problem but float type give an error?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean when using literals to call the function? `2.0` is of type double, not float. If you want a float you need to write `2.0f`. Again, it's just the rules of the language. `1` is and `int`, not `char` or `long long`. `"text"` is `cont char*` and not `std::string` etc.

Comment: Another thing that comes into play here is that if you use `float` and call the function with a double, both the conversion to `int` and `float` are narrowing conversions. So none of them is a better match -> ambigous. If you use `double` and call the function with a float, only the conversion to `int` is narrowing, but not the conversion to double, so the double function is a better match -> not ambiguous.

Comment: I got it now...thank you so much